# What's causing this bootstrapping failure in my Heroku PHP app?

Tags: php, heroku, buildpack

I haven't made any recent updates to any of my configuration but all of my deploys on my PHP app in Heroku started failing with the following error code:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
 !     ERROR: Failed to download minimal PHP for bootstrapping!
 !     
 !     This is most likely a temporary internal error. If the problem
 !     persists, make sure that you are not running a custom or forked
 !     version of the Heroku PHP buildpack which may need updating.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

Is this something directly related with Heroku or do I need to make a manual update somewhere in my config?

Comment: I'm experimenting the same problem but I think it might be a Heroku internal server error, because my project are running well in my local.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1390418/rebuilding-an-app-in-dokku-results-in-error-failed-to-download-minimal-php-for

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it indeed was an internal error with Heroku - all projects deployed fine in the morning.

That's what we get for trying to push a build at the end of the day!